# Passing in values to directive not working - AngularJS/directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some UI that will be reused in my app so I am making a directive for it. I'm following the angular examples on their website and I am trying to do this:

**Default.html**

```
 <contact-num-search info="{type: telephone}"></contact-num-search>
 <contact-num-search info="{type: email}"></contact-num-search>
```

**directives.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp');

    myAppModule.directive('contactNumSearch', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/dashboard/templates/tmplContactNumberSearch.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                info: '='
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

**tmplContactNumberSearch.html**

```
<span class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" ng-mouseenter="status.isopen = true" ng-mouseleave="status.isopen = false">
    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        {{info.type}}
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">{{info.type}}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><input type="button" value="search" /></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

My child scope in the template is an empty string:

```
{{info.type}}
```

I want it to say telephone for telephone contact number search and email for email contact number search.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to check: what is the value of `info` in the scope where you make a use of your directive? You might as well be passing in an empty value into directive there already.
Edit: nevermind... check the  type of the variable you pass in (string vs. object)

Comment: @plamut I was originally passing in some JSON that was hard-coded instead of using a scope variable as I didn't want to have scope variables for each of the 6 directives. I've posted my solution.

Comment: I see, you decided to treat the option as a string. Fair enough, that's also an option.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my directive to this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp');

    myAppModule.directive('contactNumSearch', function () {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/dashboard/templates/tmplContactNumberSearch.html',
            require: '^info',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                type: '@'
            }
        }
    });
})();



 <contact-num-search type="telephone"></contact-num-search>
 <contact-num-search type="emails"></contact-num-search>
```

By saying require for that element property I was able to pass in the text. I didn't pass in JSON in the end.

Comment: `require` doesn't have anything to do with ability to pass text. Directive scope declaration `type: '@'` makes your `type` attribute value being propagated into directive scope.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have done.

```
<contact-num-search info="{type: 'telephone'}"></contact-num-search>
<contact-num-search info="{type: 'email'}"></contact-num-search>
```

you the object wrong way.It should be like this

`info="{type: 'telephone'}"` and **not** `info="{type: email}"`

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQGOWBRR7ObCHjriziER?p=preview)